How do I create an ffmpeg-python pipeline that adds an audio (numpy) array to a set of output frames?
How do I add a numpy audio signal to a set of frames that I am sending to ffmpeg-python and storing in a file?
This code generates the proper video.  But how do I add the audio data?  The audio data is also in a numpy array and has its own sample rate.
I'm confused.  I tried adding a second .input, as I would from the command line, and that didn't work.
Thanks.
-- Malcolm
P.S. correlogram is a 3d array of B&W frames.
OUT_FILENAME = 'tapestry_correlogram.mp4'
WIDTH = correlogram.shape[2]
HEIGHT = correlogram.shape[1]
max_pixel = np.sqrt(np.max(correlogram))

writing_process = ffmpeg \
    .input('pipe:', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='rgb24', 
           s='{}x{}'.format(WIDTH, HEIGHT)) \
    .output(OUT_FILENAME, pix_fmt='yuv420p') \
    .overwrite_output() \
    .run_async(pipe_stdin=True)
 
for i in range(correlogram.shape[0]):
  frame = correlogram[i, :, :]
  frame = np.sqrt(frame)/max_pixel*255
  frame = frame.astype(np.uint8)
  frame = np.repeat(frame[:, :, np.newaxis], 3, axis=2)
  writing_process.stdin.write((255-frame).tobytes())

